# Validation in Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to set maximum limit in JQuery Datepicker so that the user can't pick date after current date. Currently I'm using http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ plugin.
How to set maximum limit in JQuery datepicker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[option-maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Z9URr/)

```
$("#date").datepicker("option","maxDate",0);
```

or

```
$("#date").datepicker("option","maxDate",new Date());
```

---

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Z9URr/1)

```
$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can validate by Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#datepicker").val() == ''){
  alert("Please Select Your date");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this- just in the datepicker function you are using pass these parameters

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
         $( "#date1" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "+30M",   
    });
```

fore more [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638740/jquery-datepicker-mindate-maxdate)