# Need to validate Date of birth user should be 18 years and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

i am using bootstrap-datepicker.js to take date of birth from calendar,i need to disabled past date and it should be enabled after 18 years in calendar.  Please help me to resolved this issue.

Comment: Use moment.js it has all the functionality required by you!

Comment: Your code is the bootstrap-datepicker plugin...? Please show us the code you wrote to attempt to solve this.

Comment: No one wants to read that wall of code and guess what your error might be. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more importantly, please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try initialising it with the max date attribute set

```
$("#datePickerId").datepicker({
    maxDate: "-18Y"
});
```

[jQuery datepicker mindate, maxdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638740/jquery-datepicker-mindate-maxdate)

Answer (score 2):

This is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment("1999-03-22").isBefore(moment().subtract(18, "years"))
```

It will return true if the date in the first parenthesis is at least 18 years ago based on the current date.